# Compiling PHP & MySQL to standalone windows or linux application

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ubuntu

For the needs of my father's store, some time ago i developed an web application using PHP and MySQL. The application is used to manage the products in the store.

Now he told me that some friend of him wants to use the application in his store too, but it's  little annoying for me to explain him how to prepare his computer for the system..

I found some ways to compile the code to .exe, but it was nowhere explained what to do with the database.

What is the best way to make it comfortable for running on other computers? Maybe i should change the database type and use some other database instead of MySQL?

Comment: PHP and MySQL aren't really meant to run "offline" - the way you want it to.

Comment: The easiest way would definitely be to just have him install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: sqlite is a lightweight portable backend.

Comment: I can understand the sentiment behind the question, and it's well asked, so I've given it a +1, but I really don't think you're going to get an answer that solves the problem the way you want. In truth, your best bet will be simply installing PHP/mySQL/Apache etc as normal. Trying to do anything else is actually likely to make things more complex rather than less complex, which will defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is [serverless](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html), and is perfect for embedding on standalone machines.